How to get updated property state in Shopify Customizer
I have a slider and I want my JS to be updated and the slider to be updated when editing in the Customizer.Why does the code now, when updating {{ section.settings.change_slides_speed }} always display the default value 5 to the console, and only if I save it will display a different value to the console. Also does not update true/false values. How can I solve this problem


<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      const initAnnouncementSlider = () => {
        console.log({{ section.settings.change_slides_speed |  json }});
        const announcementBarSlider = document.querySelector(".announcement-bar__slider");
        if (announcementBarSlider) {
          new Splide(announcementBarSlider, {
          arrows: false,
          pagination: false,
          type: 'loop',
          autoplay: {{ section.settings.auto_rotate }},
          interval: {{ section.settings.change_slides_speed }}000,
          speed: 800,
          perPage: 1,
          perMove: 1,
        }).mount();
        }
      };

      initAnnouncementSlider();

      if (Shopify.designMode) {
        document.addEventListener('shopify:section:load', initAnnouncementSlider);
        document.addEventListener('shopify:section:reorder', initAnnouncementSlider);
      }
  });
</script>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "t:sections.announcement-bar.name",
  "max_blocks": 12,
  "class": "announcement-bar-section",
  "enabled_on": {
    "groups": ["header"]
  },
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "auto_rotate",
      "label": "t:sections.announcement-bar.settings.auto_rotate.label",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "change_slides_speed",
      "min": 3,
      "max": 10,
      "step": 1,
      "unit": "s",
      "label": "t:sections.announcement-bar.settings.change_slides_speed.label",
      "default": 5
    },
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "announcement",
      "name": "t:sections.announcement-bar.blocks.announcement.name",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "text",
          "default": "Welcome to our store",
          "label": "t:sections.announcement-bar.blocks.announcement.settings.text.label"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "link",
          "label": "t:sections.announcement-bar.blocks.announcement.settings.link.label"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "t:sections.announcement-bar.presets.name",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "announcement"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}



